# TS error on iterating through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I want to loop through an array of objects in js to find the element with a specific key.

It's worth noting that, the 'specific key' will exist in only one of the objects and no more. (it is also possible the 'key' will not exist in any of the objects)

For Example:

```
const arr: [
      { foo: number; fooo: number },
      { bar: number; barr: number },
      { baz: number; bazz: number }
    ] = [
      { foo: 100, fooo: 1 },
      { bar: 3, barr: 200 },
      { baz: 0, bazz: 0 },
    ];
```

I am using below code to find the object which has the wanted key:

```
const wantedObj = arr.find((el) => (typeof el.baz !== 'undefined'))
```

Since it is possible for the `key` to have a falsey value (ex: 0 ), I am checking `(typeof el.baz !== 'undefined')` condition.

But I get the TS error of

```
Property 'bazz' does not exist on type '{ foo: number; fooo: number; } | { bar: number; barr: number; } | { baz: number; bazz: number; }'.
Property 'bazz' does not exist on type '{ foo: number; fooo: number; }'.ts(2339)
```

Why is TS giving this error while I have obviously defined the type of `arr`? and how to fix it?

Comment: Because typescript does not think that you have defined your types correctly. As you can see in the error, `bazz` does not exist on `{ foo: number; fooo: number; }`. Elements in `arr` could be of type `{ foo: number; fooo: number; }`. One way to handle that would be to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). Also see [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript union of Array and Object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519831/typescript-union-of-array-and-object-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every object in `arr` has a `baz` property. That's why the type of `el` inside the `find` looks like this:

```
{
    foo: number;
    fooo: number;
} | {
    bar: number;
    barr: number;
} | {
    baz: number;
    bazz: number;
}
```

Whenever you have a union of different object types, you can only access *shared* properties with the dot-notation.

We have to narrow the type of `el` first before accessing `baz`. The `in` operator let's us check an object for *any* property. Even those which are not defined in its type. The `in` operator also lets us *narrow* the union to those elements where the property exists.

```
const wantedObj = arr.find((el): el is Extract<typeof el, { baz: any }> => 
  "baz" in el && typeof el.baz !== "undefined"
);

wantedObj?.baz
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhgbQFAxgbxgMxBFTAFcBbAIwFMEBuAo4mMq2mAXwBotcZLEJCjXr9EKFsPbdeeAQC8hbUQsWTlnDAF0YAXnSzGzAIwAGU1yMnOPbHMEwAzJYFJUAJnM3DC1BbHyaqbeWnQYGKCQsADucGBQ1AAmAPKUAFZ68EgAdPgAlmCJABRF1AA2AJR6AHwwAEQKdTAFMOUwAGTtMFAAngAO1CD4rWXZCjAAhLr6daSF1PlgSXUVYUA)

Comment: If we narrow it down with `"baz" in el`, then there is no need to check the second condition. right? (removing the second condition doesn't change anything i think)

Comment: You should keep it. `baz` could still be set with `undefined`. `"baz" in el` would return true, even if it is undefined.

Comment: Can't TS infer the type of `wantedObj`? In the playground link, I am still getting error on accessing `wantedObj?.baz`

Comment: @AliBaghban - See my edit. You are gonna need a *type predicate*. Without a type predicate, `find` just returns the same type as the source array. The type predicate tells TypeScript to modify the type.